# When applying for jobs how to indicate I can't do phone interviews without alerting red flags?

Tags: interviewing, communication

I want to start applying for web design/developer jobs.

This would be the first time for me.

Phone interviews (or even confirmed by phone) must be a thing, right?

I have a speech problem. Face to face I'm sort of fine but on the phone, I'd be useless.

How can I deal with this?

I don't want to be in danger of oversharing and as a result for my resume to be set aside.

Edit - more information

I have cerebral palsy. I've taken my time to try and improve it (gym mostly), now I can say with full confidence I'm could be a valuable member of any team with no special requirements.

The only problem is my speech. I find face to face interactions are a lot easier then over the phone (with the help of gestures, body language and so on).

I'm trying to figure out if phone interviews are something that is done frequently, would I be at a disadvantage if, therefore, I'm not available for them? Are they done only sometimes, therefore if I keep applying there will be enough companies that don't require phone interviews?

Comment: What speech problem only happens on phone?

Comment: Would you have the same speech problem on a  video interview?

Comment: @Kilisi In that face to face, it's easier to get the point across. Honestly, over the phone is much worse.

Comment: Thats not a speech problem, it's a communication one.

Comment: How is skype any different from a phone call? What makes you able to communicate better over that than a phone call?

Answer (score 6):

Whether your request would cause a red flag all depends on how you phrase it.

Don't just say:

> I can't do phone interviews due to a speech problem.

Say something like:

> I would prefer on site interviews, but if that is not possible a Skype/video conference interview work well for me.

As long as you phrase your request in a positive manner, the recruiter should not have any issues trying to accommodate you.  Just keep in mind that some companies do conduct phone interviews and you may be limiting your opportunities.

Comment: Yep, always offer what you really want, not what you don't want. Rather than saying, "I can't..." say "I can..." excluding the thing you don't like. If they can't take the hint, then something is very wrong.

Comment: I shouldn't say anything in the cover letter, only when they contact me, or put this in the cover letter?

Answer (score 2):

They'll contact you by email first (people are busy, and won't be available to take a phone call with no warning). If they do so and ask when you're available for a phone interview, respond with something of the form "I have a disability that makes phone conversations hard. Can I have a face-to-face interview please?"

Comment: When do you suggest OP to mention this?

Comment: That's it, but when is the right time to mention it

Comment: When asked if they're available for a phone interview.

Comment: @user3482749 so leave the phone number out of the cv and just provide email?

Comment: @Cimi I've never heard of anybody conducting phone interviews, or doing really any other part of the hiring process, by just ringing with no warning - people are either working (and unable to take the call), or possibly out shopping or something (and therefore unable to have an interview). It's always an email first of the form "are you available for a phone call at such and such a time?". I'd probably leave the phone number on there, purely because people expect to see it, but I'd be very surprised if anybody rang it.

Comment: @user3482749 and upon the email state that I prefer face to face, right?

Comment: @Cimi Yes, exactly.

Comment: @user3482749 if you included such detail in your answer it will improve its quality. It's best to put those things in answers, as comments are ephemeral

Comment: It may be that Cimi has a formal medical diagnosis, but I've not seen that in the question so far. Without a formal medical diagnosis, saying "I have a disability" would raise a big red flag. On the other hand, "I have a speech problem that makes phone conversations hard" is something that could be said without formal diagnosis.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere i have cerebral palsy. It wouldn't really affect me to do my job just speech is a problem. The problem is extremely emphasized over the phone.

Comment: @Cimi - Thanks for the additional information. In that case the answer is fine as it stands. All the best.